# Effective upper bound for a sum over prime numbers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

Fix $y$ a positive real number. Is there an effective bound for the following sum i.e a positive constant B such that
$$\sum_{p>y}\sum_{\nu \geq 4} \frac{1}{p^{9\nu/32}} \leq B.$$
Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that only considering the $\nu = 2$ terms gives $\frac{1}{p^{9/16}} > \frac{1}{p}$, and the sum of reciprocals of the primes [diverges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_of_the_sum_of_the_reciprocals_of_the_primes), so your sum is unbounded.